# AppleScript to keystroke too fast for flash

Tags: applescript

This works fine with input-fields in desktop applications and html-based websites:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "HelloWorld"
```

However, in our Flash-application (run in Chrome) it seems the keystroke is too fast. In the input-field it only enters "eol".

Has people run in to this behaviour before with flash?

Is there some good fix or do I have to do the work-around of splitting the word up into characters and keystroking each character separate (with an optional delay between each)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
set myText to "HelloWorld"
set myChar to characters of myText
set myDelay to 0.5

tell application "System Events"
    repeat with aChar in myChar
        keystroke aChar
        delay myDelay
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: `characters of` was quite beautiful. I changed delay to 0.01 with ok results. Thanks!

Comment: @Cotten is the `myChar` variable necessary? Could you do `repeat with aChar in myText` directly?